# Laravel Job deserialzation wrong class

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, deserialization, jobs

I've got a problem while using Laravel's job Deserialization. 
This is the Job class that is queued in the database:

```
class SendRatingEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $order, $user;

    public function __construct(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->order->isRatedByUser($this->user->id)) {
            return;
        }
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->queue(new RatingEmail($this->order, $this->user));
    }
}
```

In the class `Order.php`, I dispatch this job like this:

```
class Order {
    function queueRating()
    {
        $when = Carbon::now()->addDays(env('ORDER_DAYS_RATING', 8));
        dispatch((new SendRatingEmail($this->buyer, $this))->delay($when));
    }
}
```

So the problem is in the job's `handle()` function, specifically the error is:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isRatedByUser()
```

It seems as though Laravel gives me the wrong object, instead of `App\Order` it gives me the QueryBuilder. In the `queueRating()` function I have checked that the types given in the constructor are the expected types. I have even tested a workaround which also didn't seem to work:

```
if($this->order instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder) {
    $this->order = $this->order->first();
}
```

Also I have looked in the jobs table, and it seems as if the saved models are correct (`App\Order`)

**Edit**

Here is the code where the `queueRating()` function is called. The file is `StripeController` which handles credit card payments.

```
public function orderPaid($order) {
    $order->payment_done = 1;
    $order->save();

    $order->chat->open = 1;
    $order->chat->save();

    $order->queueRating();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're calling `queueRating`?  Also, inside your `queueRating` method (before `$when`) try calling the `isRatedByUser` method and seeing if it works.

Comment: @RossWilson I edited my question to include the code.

Comment: Did calling the `isRatedByUser` method inside `queueRating` method work? Also, inside the `handle` method of your job double check that the `Order` exists i.e. (`$this->order->exists`).

Comment: @RossWilson as it turns out i only needed to restart the queue worker to fix this issue. I feel so stupid not thinking about this. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, as always the problem is not where I looked. As it turns out, the code is completely fine, but I forgot to restart the queue worker on the staging server, which meant that changes in the code base were not applied in the queue worker. So the application and queue used different versions.

It is even stated in the [Laravel Queue Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker):

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

I use the bugtracker [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/), which shows the error and also the line numbers in the code. I had noticed that the line number where the error occurred mismatched the real line number, but couldn't figure out that this was causing the problem.